# implement server side processing and Ajax interaction for the Grid.MVC plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, grid.mvc

I am working on an asp.net mvc  web application, and I want to use the Grid.MVC plugin found at this link http://gridmvc.codeplex.com/ . So I did the following:-

From the NuGet package I installed the Grid.MVC to my project.

The I added the following to my view:-

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebApplication30.Models.Employee>
    @using GridMvc.Html
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <div style="width:500px;">
        @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Add(c => c.FName).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FName).ToString()).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(c => c.LName).Titled(Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LName).ToString()).Filterable(true);
                            columns.Add(c => c.Dept.DeptName).Titled("deptname").Filterable(true);;
                        }).WithPaging(3).Sortable(true)
    </div>
```

The model looks as follow:-

```
public partial class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LName { get; set; }
        public int DeptID { get; set; }

        public virtual Dept Dept { get; set; }
    }
```

And the controller is:-

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Dept);
            return View(employees.ToList());
        }
```

Now the paging + column sorting is working well. But I am facing these issues with them:-

1. Paging + column sort will lead to full page re-load. So can I specify Ajax based interaction?
2. Paging+ column sort will be done on the client side, so each time I visit the view, I will be retrieving the whole data from the database . so is there a way to do this on the server side.